# Typescript: Dynamically Assign Properties On Class

Tags: typescript

I have a class that binds variable data onto its instance.

```
class RouteData{
  constructor(data: Object) {
    // binding object attributes to instance
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => { this[key] = data[key];})
  }
}

let route: RouteData = new RouteData({hello: "test"})
console.log(route.hello);
```

The result of the above is `test`.

However, I do get an error while compiling.

`example.ts(9,19): error TS2339: Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'RouteData'.`

How can I declare the type of this class to allow for binding of any property on its class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a cast  before.

```
console.log((<any>route).hello);
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to declare interfaces as:

```
interface IHello {
    hello: string;
}

interface IRouteDataHello extends RouteData, IHello { }

let route = <IRouteDataHello>new RouteData(<IHello>{ hello: "test" })

console.log(route.hello);
```

This makes compiler to do static checking and allow you to refactor code with ease (that's what TypeScript is for). Of course it is not important for a small project.

For example instead of `IHello` it can be more complex object:

```
interface IRouteData<T> {
    path: string;
    component: { new () };
    as?: string;
    data?: T;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Artem. The reason I'm trying it this way is because the bindings I'm apply are unknow. I'm not sure if hello will be the name of the key or that it will be a string.

See the data.

  `new Route({path: '/drafts', component: DraftsCmp, as: 'drafts', data: {isAdmin: false}})`